# Error with a Python script neamed Phaster

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I've installed [PHASTER](https://github.com/boulund/phaster_scripts) by cloning the Github directory into my HOME folder. However, after typing the command

```
phaster.py --contigs --fasta path/to/genome.fasta
```

I got this error which read

> 2019-07-11 14:32:02,389 INFO: Submission of TH19.fna appears
>   successful
>
> 2019-07-11 14:32:02,390 INFO:   job_id: ZZ_0f276b0c53
>
> 2019-07-11 14:32:02,390 INFO:   error: The sequence header is not on
>   the first line. Please check!
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/fox/phaster_scripts/phaster.py", line 162, in
>
> ```
> job_id, status, date = submit_job(fasta, options.url, {"contigs": int(options.contigs)})
> ```
>
> File "/home/fox/phaster_scripts/phaster.py", line 99, in submit_job
>       return r_dict["job_id"], r_dict["status"], datetime.datetime.now()
>
> KeyError: 'status'

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with phaster scripts [check this](https://github.com/boulund/phaster_scripts/issues/2)

Comment: Thank @Prasun, and could you please suggest other tools for plasmid detection?